# Playa only returning children in same channel

Tags: playa

EE 2.3.1
Playa 4.4.5
I'm just looking to return the children for a given entry.
Playa is only returning the children that are in the same channel as the parent.
This works as expected on my testing server (EE2.6.1).
This is all that is in the template.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="slider"}
<h3>{title}-{entry_id}</h3>
 <ul>
{slider_articles}
<li>{title}</li>
{/slider_articles}
 </ul>
{exp:playa:total_children}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

yet specifying  {exp:playa:child_ids entry_id="1234"} returns all the correct related id's.
All the data looks correct in the exp_playa_relationships table.

Answer (score 1):

Doh!
I didn't realize the client had a custom status on those entries.

This fixed it:

{slider_articles status="open|Published"}

It's been one of those weeks.....................